# JCIFS - How to get name of last modified file in folder?

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

How to get name of last modified file in a folder using JCIFS? I don't want to use a loop. 
I found methods `lastModified()` and `getDate()`, but they give me a set of random numbers (they do not look like 'a date' at all).

Comment: How about loading them all into a list, sorting the list, then selecting the last one in the result list?

Answer (score 0):

probably it's late...

`lastModified()` and `getDate()`

return the number of milliseconds since the 00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970 as a long value

You can convert these values to LocalDateTime for example:

```
public static LocalDateTime longToDate(long msec){
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(msec), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return date;
    }
```